# NullPointerException when object is initialized in another method

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, binary-tree

I was trying to learn about binary trees and `NullPointerException`were coming. So I decided to write a little program to try to understand it. Here is the code:

```
public class Nulls
{
    static Node node;
    private class Node
    {
        int val;
        Node right;
        Node left;
    }
    public void init(Node n)
    {
        if(n==null)n=new Node();
    }
    public void print()
    {
         System.out.println(node);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Nulls n=new Nulls();
        n.init(node);
        n.print();
    }
}
```

The output was `null`. If I understand properly, the node object was initialized and the output should be the object's `toString()` method. And as the `print()` method is executed after `init(Node n)`, the output should not be `null`. What is the problem?

Comment: Go read this - http://javadude.com/articles/passbyvalue.htm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The root cause is that in Java arguments are passed by value, which means, when you pass a (reference to) node `n` as an argument, you're actually passing a copy of the reference to that node, which is `null` at that time. Since you're changing the copy-reference, nothing is really assigned and the new Node that you create in the `init` is eligible to GC when `init` has done executing.

But that's easy to fix:

```
public class Nulls {

    static Node node;

    private class Node {
        int val;
        Node right;
        Node left;
    }

    public void init() {
        if(node==null) {
            node=new Node();
        }
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(node);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Nulls n=new Nulls();
        n.init();
        n.print();
    }
}
```

Comment: A personal comment is for me to ask, is the reason that it's being passed as a reference to the object because it's static? Or is there more to it?

Comment: @CoderMusgrove No, static/non-static has nothing to do with it. In Java everything is passed by value. The confusing part is that *references* are passed by value as well, meaning, when you pass a reference to an object, what is actually passed is a new reference that is pointing to the same object. If you use that new reference to change the object - you'll see the changes after you exit the method because the original reference is referring to the same object.

Comment: (continue:) In our case the original reference was pointing to `null`, and what the OP tried to do was to change the reference *itself* which cannot be done when you pass-by-value.

Comment: It's the same situation as `public void init(int i) {if(i == 0) i = 42;}` `public static void main(String[] args) {int x = 0; init(x); System.out.println(x); /* why is x still 0? */}`